# How to Get Text Values of a Radio button list that is nested in a data list

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net, html

I have a radiobuttonlist inside datalist which displays a question (as a header) and all its possible answers (as radio buttons)

check below code

```
        <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="DataList1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
      DataKeyField="Question_ID" onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
      <ItemTemplate>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3><%#Eval("Question")%></h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the below is .cs

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TMConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);

        //Getting All Questions

        SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Question ", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dr.Fill(ds, "Qs");
        DataList1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Qs"];
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            RadioButtonList RadioButtonList1 = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
            //Get questionID here
            int QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem,"Question_ID"));

            //pass Question ID to your DB and get all available options for the question
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TMConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter("select Answer,AnswerID from Answer where Qid="+QuestionID+"", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dr.Fill(ds, "Answers");
            RadioButtonList1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Answers"];
            RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "Answer";
            RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "AnswerID";
            RadioButtonList1.DataBind();


        }
    }
```

all i need is to collect the answers in one textarea .
how can i do this using JQuery ? any idea ?

note : when i run the page and check page source i notice that it automatically rename the answers control to Datalist1_radiobuttonlist 1_0 and then Datalist1_radiobuttonlist 1_1 , etc . .

Comment: it will be better if you can share the generated html

Comment: show us ur generated html, and to prevent ur html control being renamed by asp, then just add  ClientIDMode="Static" to your asp components, ur components id won't change.

Answer (score 0):

I have collected the answer in the textbox. You can do this each time and append the answeres like

```
$(".radiovalues").val($(".radiovalues").val()+"|"+val);
```

this will keep storing and appending answers seperated by "|" . Later you can split it with "|".

You can do something as follows

HTML As below (Note: this is the sample generated html code of radiobuttonlist.)

```
<div id="radioList"> 
<input type="text" class="radiovalues" value="">    
    <table id="rbtLstRating" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input id="rbtLstRating_0" type="radio" name="rbtLstRating" value="Excellent"><label for="rbtLstRating_0">Excellent</label></td><td><input id="rbtLstRating_1" type="radio" name="rbtLstRating" value="Very Good"><label for="rbtLstRating_1">Very Good</label></td><td><input id="rbtLstRating_2" type="radio" name="rbtLstRating" value="Good"><label for="rbtLstRating_2">Good</label></td><td><input id="rbtLstRating_3" type="radio" name="rbtLstRating" value="Fair"><label for="rbtLstRating_3">Fair</label></td><td><input id="rbtLstRating_4" type="radio" name="rbtLstRating" value="Bad"><label for="rbtLstRating_4">Bad</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Javascript as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name=rbtLstRating]').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        //alert(val);
        $(".radiovalues").val(val);
    });

});
```

And this is the [jsfiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/passionintellectual/gm36pkj6/1/